# Automated Script to Visit URLs

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, automation, xampp

I am creating a simple web application using PHP, Codeigniter and Google Books (on an WIndows 7 XAMPP localhost environment).

I have a MySQL list of books (a few hundred) and corresponding ISBN numbers. When a user views a book / visits a URL for the first time, and API call is made to Google Books and the title, author and description of the book is saved to my database.

Ideally i'd like to populate the database myself and not rely on the user. So, I was thinking of visiting each URL manually. However there a lot of items!

Is there a script I can use for such a task? I was hoping to run the script once every 5 minutes over a 24 hour period.

My URL is in the following format:

```
/items/itemView/1 // <-- book 1
/items/itemView/2 // <-- book 2
/items/itemView/3 // <-- book 3
// etc
// etc
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use a loop & make calls to Google Books API? Then fetch all info & save in your DB.

Comment: What's the problem with that?

Comment: From your description of question, it seems u've already built different pieces of codes which you can re-use to built this one also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

A storage API exists so you don't have to catalogue everything.

**Long Answer:**

It sounds like what you are trying to do is take the API and scour through *every single entry* and record them for your own purposes.

While this can usually done fairly simply, instead of telling you how to do this, I'm going to tell you *why you shouldn't*.

An API to a huge database exists so that you don't have to store it all, as the resources required can be absolutely huge, usually more than most enthusiasts would even have.

It's better to have it as you do now, cache what is visited on the chance it is visited again and make sure periodically that any records you DO keep, you compare to it's source so that you don't have an out-of-date record (another pitfall of local caching).

I hope this helps at least show you why people tend not to duplicate large data sources.

Comment: @johnny_s Thank you :) I'm always happy to help people along where I can, if you are happy with my answer please mark it as accepted. :P

Comment: @johnny_s I think sometimes people tend to jump the gun is all, I wouldn't take it personally. I will upvote the question for the sake of educating others with a similar quandry.